# Ionic - trouble with accessing an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a web service that returns an object called response.  It has an object data.  When I do the following:

```
  var myObject = JSON.stringify(response.data);
  console.log("My Results: " + myObject);
```

> [{"id":"1","username":"sam","user_id":"1","status":"1"}]

But I am having trouble accessing these objects in a scope.

for example

```
$scope.myresponse = response.data;
$scope.myresponse.username = response.data.username
```

It doesn't work.  I even tried `$scope.myresponse = response.data[0];`  that didnt' work either.  Any suggestions?

Comment: show us your $http method that may help you to identify the error

Comment: show your code please

Comment: $http.post('http://www.mywww.com/dosomething?token='+mytoken, postData).then(function(response) {

           var myObject = JSON.stringify(response.data);
           console.log("My Results: " + myObject);

Comment: Please post your whole code here(controller and service's code).

Comment: the postData is var postData = {
                my data elements that I am posting.  In return I run a query to get the objects back.  Post is successful. and query returns the right results.  
                };

Comment: Ashish - the code has some sensitive data handling that i unfortunately cannot share.   The challenge I have is accessing the objects in the array.  It is acting like a multi-dimensional array even though there is only one record that is returned.

Comment: @joti store response inside some service variable and use that variable to get the required data... please do tell what type of error you are getting, that would be helpful in tracking the error...

Comment: Ajay - can you please post an example code?   I am fairly new to Angularjs/Ionic.  Started working on it only 6 months ago and still learning.

Comment: Just want to confirm, what is the type of response? It is working when I did var a = JSON.parse('[{"id":"1","username":"sam","user_id":"1","status":"1"}]'); console.log(a[0].id);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store response return from backend call inside a service layer variable and access that variable from controller to get the required result.

Demo code showing above interaction...

In ServiceLayer.js

```
var myObject = response["data"];

function getMyObject() {
    return myObject;    
}
```

In Controller.js

Inject that registered service and access myObject variable.

```
$scope.myresponse = this.serviceLayer.getMyObject();
```

use this myResponse variable to access any required information.

Regards

Ajay

Comment: Thanks.  I will attempt this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the solution turned out be an easy one.  Not very clean but it works.

$scope.myData = response.data;
        $scope.myResults = $scope.myData[0];

After this I was able to access all the elements e.g. id by {{myResults.id}} in my view.

Thank you all for your help.